# Where does Nautilus get its file type description

Tags: nautilus, mime-types

I've created and registered some shared-mime-info files for custom file types. For example, in

```
~/.local/share/mime/packages
```

I've added files like

```
x-myokit.xml
```

containing a mime type description, for example

```
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/x-myokit">
    <comment xml:lang="en">Myokit model definition</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.mmt"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Nautilus now recognises my files, but still displays the file type as "Unknown". How do I make it show something more useful in this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was hardcoded in `Nautilus` as per the devs decision to [only show basic type information](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-September/msg07135.html) in the `Type` column by default, so that sorting by type would group type families.
The basic types are defined in [nautilus-file.c](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/tree/libnautilus-private/nautilus-file.c) based on generic (symbolic) icon names<sup>1</sup>:

```c
struct {
        const char *icon_name;
        const char *display_name;
} mime_type_map[] = {
    { "application-x-executable", N_("Program") },
    { "audio-x-generic", N_("Audio") },
    { "font-x-generic", N_("Font") },
    { "image-x-generic", N_("Image") },
    { "package-x-generic", N_("Archive") },
    { "text-html", N_("Markup") },
    { "text-x-generic", N_("Text") },
    { "text-x-generic-template", N_("Text") },
    { "text-x-script", N_("Program") },
    { "video-x-generic", N_("Video") },
    { "x-office-address-book", N_("Contacts") },
    { "x-office-calendar", N_("Calendar") },
    { "x-office-document", N_("Document") },
    { "x-office-presentation", N_("Presentation") },
    { "x-office-spreadsheet", N_("Spreadsheet") },
};
```

Types that do not fall in the above categories are shown as `Unknown`:

```c
if (basic_type == NULL) {
    basic_type = g_strdup (_("Unknown"));
```

As a result,  a file with mime type `application/x-myokit` (with a corresponding symbolic icon name `application-x-generic`) will be listed as `Unknown` in the `Type` column while a file with mime type `text/x-myokit` (with a corresponding symbolic icon name `text-x-generic`) will be listed as `Text` in the `Type` column (see also various system files like `*.so` files under `/usr/lib` or `*.mo` files in `/usr/share/locale` - they're all listed as `Unknown` but if you select one of them and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you get detailed, accurate information).

---

You can make Nautilus list something else if you use `generic-icon name` in your `xml` file. Though your options are limited to the above mentioned categories. So, e.g. if you wanted each of your `*.mmt` files to be listed as `Program` in the `Type` column you would edit your `x-myokit.xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/x-myokit">
        <comment>Myokit model definition</comment>
        <generic-icon name="text-x-script"/>
        <glob pattern="*.mmt"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Don't forget to update the mime database with:

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

If you need more useful informations you could enable/check the `MIME type` column in `Nautilus` preferences (or with `dconf`/`gsettings`: add `mime_type` to `org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-visible-columns`).

<sup>1: run `gio info -a standard::symbolic-icon file` to see the corresponding symbolic icon names (on older setups replace `gio info` with `gvfs-info`)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I believe Nautilus gets the file description from the location `/usr/share/applications`. You could find more useful information from my other answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149038/47538). Particularly, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/16583/334241) answer in Ask Ubuntu discusses how the file assosiciations are stored in detail.

> The file manager (Nautilus, by default) uses the MIME type of a
>   file to determine which program to open it with.  When an application
>   is installed, it can specify what MIME types it can open and the
>   command to use to open the files in the .desktop file which is placed
>   in `/usr/share/applications`. This is the file used for menus, desktop
>   shortcuts, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I've updated my answer to show I've already added a file letting nautilus determine the mime types. If I don't have any application registered and double-click, it says something like 'No application registered for files of type "Myokit model definition"' which shows that it reads and uses these mime type files. However, in the column "Type" it still shows something useless like "Unknown" or "text". My question is how to change this.

Comment: @MichaelClerx, ok. Let me check. I am not aware of this but will update the answer if I find any.